# ido-mode distinguish dired-mode buffer names

Tags: emacs, elisp

does anyone know of a good way to distinguish dired-mode buffer names from other types of buffers in the minibuffer while using ido-mode? For instance... showing a forward-slash at end of a dired-mode buffer name?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a way there, but the feature looks useful.  I suggest to send a feature request to bug-gnu-emacs@gnu.org.

Comment: Thanks - but Trey's solution is quite nice for both ido and dired modes... might stick with this one...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could simply change the `dired-mode` buffers to always have `/`s at the end of their names.  This code does that.

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'ensure-buffer-name-ends-in-slash)
(defun ensure-buffer-name-ends-in-slash ()
  "change buffer name to end with slash"
  (let ((name (buffer-name)))
    (if (not (string-match "/$" name))
        (rename-buffer (concat name "/") t))))
```

Comment: One problem though: it doesn't resolve name conflicts nicely when two directories have the same name.

Comment: @WeiHu - Of course not, the question wasn't asking for a solution to that problem.  I personally use uniquify for resolving similarly named buffers: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html

Comment: my point was that with your solution, opening two directories with identical names would issue an annoying error message, and the one opened later wouldn't have `/` at the end.